# Mask file path

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting, filepath

I am developing a site based on Drupal CMS and it has awesome image managing tools but there is a problem: While the images are being nicely resides rotated or else their paths become a bit weird for a common user.

It just so happens that users will see a lot of my images urls and I want them to look short, nice, and pretty. Since there is powerful module called Pathauto for Drupal users I just thought that changing masking files original url could be as simple as nodes.

Could it be that easy? If so, how? Maybe there is more than one way to do it? Could some non-Drupal way do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try editing the htaccess file. It seems someone else has had that same thought... [Drupal alias your file paths using htaccess](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-alias-your-file-paths-using-htaccess)